# Does mypy require __init__ to have -> None annotation

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Seeing kind of contradictory results:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        pass
```

The snippet above passes a `mypy` test, but the one below doesn't.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is documented [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/class_basics.html#annotating-init-methods).

When you have at least one (annotated) argument for a function, it is considered (at least partially) typed. When neither arguments nor return values are annotated, the function is considered **untyped**.

This distinction is important because by default, `mypy` does not check the bodies of [untyped functions](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html?highlight=untyped#untyped-definitions-and-calls) at all. This behavior is configurable via `check_untyped_defs`.

Note that the complaint about the missing return type only arises, if you set `disallow_untyped_defs` (or `strict`). Otherwise neither of your examples will trigger an error.

The `__init__` method receives special treatment because people complained that always returns `None` and they did not want to explicitly write out the return type accordingly. This is why that behavior is so inconsistent.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x: int):  # this is fine with `mypy`
        pass

    def foo(self, x: int):
        print("hi")


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo(self):
        print("hi")
```

Out of all these methods, only `A.__init__` is considered fully typed (because of the implicit `None` return by `__init__`). All the other methods will trigger errors with `disallow_untyped_defs` set:

```
error: Function is missing a return type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
```

I don't particularly like this approach, but that is the way they decided to handle it.